# How to make layout with physics effect in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I want to make animation with physics effect like this app : http://capptivate.co/2014/08/26/up-coffee/

[image]

Can I do it with Java(Android) and xml layout? 
Is there any library that can do it?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: I don't have any idea to solve this issue :( I think Android native code cannot do it and don't have any experience for game physics

Comment: Ok, in that case I'm voting to close this as too broad. There's no way to answer this question without providing you a tutorial.

Comment: I resolved this issue by using Android AndEngine and embedded AndEngine to native :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/)
The first I created a scene with my map.
After that I using [AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension) to make Physics Effect.
The last I embedded scene game to layout xml